# An equilateral triangle of Gaussian primes

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry

Let $Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ and $Z_{3}$ be 3 Gaussian primes.

Is there an equilateral triangle whose vertices are $Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ and $Z_{3}$?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. If $z_1, z_2, z_3 \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ are vertices of an equilateral triangle ordered in counterclockwise manner, then for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$\frac{a + bi}{c+di} = \frac{z_3 -z_1}{z_2 - z_1} = e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}
\quad\implies\quad  \sqrt{3} = 2\left(\frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2}\right) \in \mathbb{Q}
$$
Since $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, this is impossible.